# Moving Laravel Core Files to private_html Directory

Tags: php, laravel-7

As a security precaution, my boss has requested I move my Laravel 7 app outside the public_html folder and into private_html.

So my directory structure looks like this:

```
public_html/public/

private_html/ <-- All the rest of the Laravel core files, app, config, routes, .env, etc.
```

Now, as expected since I moved the files, I'm getting an HTTP ERROR 500 when I visited the the website.

How do I tell Laravel where my public folder is so can get back to serving my web pages? Which configuration files do I need to edit?

Thanks for any help.

Edit 1: After trying Youssef's suggestion, everything worked great except when I run

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I get:

[image]

Edit 2:

I was able to fix "php artisan storage:link" by opening config/filesystems.php and changing:

```
'links' => [
    public_path('storage') => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

To:

```
'links' => [
    '/new/directory/public_html/public/storage' => storage_path('app/public'),
],
```

Then, when I type:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

A new symlink is created.

Comment: in public/index.php  change path of required files to load them from your private_html directory

Comment: Can you show an example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In public/index.php change path of this two files to current path of them.

first line path of autoload.php

```
__DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

to

```
require __DIR__.'/../../private_html/vendor/autoload.php';
```

second line path of app.php

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
```

to

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../private_html/bootstrap/app.php';
```

and put this in the `\App\Providers\AppServiceProvider` `register()` method to set path of public directory.

```
**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    // ...

    $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/../public_html/public';
    });
}
```

finally reassign path of storage directory if you need access to stored files directly, using command :

```
php artisan storage:link
```

you can also move all files from `public_html/public` to `public_html` and adjust paths I mentioned above